# How can I get a semi-opaque css background overlay to display in landscape?

Tags: html, css, sass

My overlay, a semi-transparent background on top of my background, doesn't display properly when you rotate a screen from portrait to landscape.

Not sure how to fix this.

```
$primary-color: #313030;
$secondary-color: #d4fe01;
$show-home-image: true;
$home-image: url(../img/background.jpg);
$background-opacity: 0.8;

@mixin easeOut {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

// hmm

@mixin background {
  @if $show-home-image {
    &#bg-img {
      background: $home-image;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: cover;

      &:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
        background: rgba($primary-color, $background-opacity);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://github.com/shimanopower/newPortfolio/blob/master/dist/img/projects/LearnTerminalAssets/Screen%20Shot%202019-07-06%20at%206.56.30%20PM.png

https://github.com/shimanopower/newPortfolio/blob/master/dist/img/projects/LearnTerminalAssets/audreysmonsters.com_(iPhone%20X)%20(1).png

the site w the overlay: https://audreysmonsters.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a different style when the screen orientation is in landscape with the CSS. suggest that you increase the height of you after pseudo element when you are in the landscape orientation and in mobile with a media querie.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 812px) and (orientation: landscape){
    #bg-img:after{
        height: 120%;
    }
}
```

Comment: after adding that rule it seems to get overridden by some other property. it's listed with rule struck-through in dev tools. not sure why.

Comment: overruled by the 100% rule apparently because it still leaves a small gap uncovered in iPhone x. when I increase the @media from 120% to 130% the property is actually applied. It's still kind of imperfect solution because then it adds scrolling for the extra bottom space added. I don't get why auto height doesn't work either.

Comment: actually kind of interesting because the 100% gets overruled with the non 130% scenarios so that there is only an overlay in mobile with that rule.

Comment: Please, verify the CSS rules and classes importance order. I tested in my devtools and working fine. After I added !important worked.

Comment: You're right that if I add !important that it will apply that rule in to mobile widescreen. But it introduces another problem. That the overlay isn't there at all in non-mobile. I'll post more details in the the original question section.

Comment: actually you're right it works after you add !important (but for the small strip it leaves on the bottom on iPhone X so might want to do 130%). didn't work first time I tried because of some previous changes i forgot about it. after I stashed those changes !important worked

Comment: Very good shimanopower! A tip I give it to avoid the maximum use the `!important` in your attributes, because this may cause some problems of importance. I suggest you separete your media queries well even to better organize your CSS. Thanks!!!